# Tomcat: Reload context vs. restart single application

Tags: tomcat, restart

just a short question on tomcat:

We're using psi-probe to deploy, undeploy and restart applications.

We just had a little discussion about how to restart an application correctly. One of my devs said, we need to shutdown the single application and restart it, to have it clean.

My point was, that psi probe has a "reload context" button. This seems to work absolutely correct.

But my dev said, that just reloading a context will remain classes in memory which will never be freed unless the app is restarted.

So who's right? What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Jan